# How to improve hand independence?

Tags: competitive-gaming, moba

Suppose there is a fast-paced game that requires you to do one thing with your left hand (e.g., WASD movement) and another with your right hand (e.g., aim/act).

More often than not my focus goes on one hand, and the other one goes on autopilot. Is there an exercise that could help your brain improve its hand independence?

Note: There is a ton of info from the Piano players on how to improve hand independence but that's more at the level of the fingers and most of them involve playing the Piano. What I am more interested in is a way to do it off the piano.

Comment: Hi Sobhan, welcome to Arqade! I like these kinds of questions, but I think yours need some more details: what kind of fast-paced game are you talking about? How much experience do you have already?